# Make a change in vocabulary's keys

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, iterator

Let's say I have a vocabulary

```
public Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

Keys - 1, ..., n

Now I want delete let's say the 5th element, but want to keep normal numeration.

To have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9....
Instead of 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, ....

How to do it?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a List instead? The indexes would "keep the normal numeration"

Comment: Using `Dictionary` is not really good here, as it does not prevent any order. You should probably look at `SortedList<T>`

Comment: I pass the indices myself.

Comment: maybe a SortedDictionary? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it will work of course, BUT i need to pass keys myself

Comment: If you want delete value but key must be reachable maybe it is possible to assign null to value?

Comment: @Mike you can pass keys to sorteddictionary (in fact you have to)

Comment: @wudzik could you write it as an answer with a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define this utility method:

```
public static IDictionary<int, T> RemoveItem<T>(IDictionary<int, T> dict, int key)
{
    return dict.Where(kv => kv.Key != key)
               .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key > key ? kv.Key - 1 : kv.Key,
                             kv => kv.Value);
}
```

And then just call it like this:

```
var twoRemoved = RemoveItem(dict, 2);
```

Note that this does not modify the original dictionary object, but creates a new one with the keys after `key` shifted down by 1 and the original item with key value `key` removed.

Here's a version that *does* modify the original dictionary and may provide slightly better performance and memory usage:

```
public static void RemoveItem2<T>(IDictionary<int, T> dict, int key)
{
    dict.Remove(key);
    T item;
    while (dict.TryGetValue(++key, out item))
    {
        dict.Remove(key);
        dict[key - 1] = item;               
    }
}
```